# How to parse nested nodes in xml to csv in java

Tags: java, xml, csv

I may be overlooking the solution here, but I need help converting xml to csv with multiple nested nodes. The xml I am given looks like the following sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<familyResponse>
  <results>
    <childResults>
      <childName>Mary</childName>
      <childAge>8</childAge>
    </childResults>
    <childResults>
      <childName>Jason</childName>
      <childAge>10</childAge>
    </childResults>
    <childResults>
      <childName>Ashley</childName>
      <childAge>15</childAge>
    </childResults>
    <parentResults>
      <parentName>Theresa</parentName>
      <parentAge>35</parentAge>
    </parentResults>
  </results>
  <results>
    <parentResults>
      <parentName>Tom</parentName>
      <parentAge>21</parentAge>
    </parentResults>
  </results>
  <results>
    <childResults>
      <childName>Tori</childName>
      <childAge>2</childAge>
    </childResults>
    <parentResults>
      <parentName>Sheila</parentName>
      <parentAge>19</parentAge>
    </parentResults>
  </results>
</familyResponse>
```

There will always be a parentResults with 1 entry. There may not always be a childResults entry and there can also be multiple childResults entries. If there is no childResults entry, I don't need to put the parentResults in the file, I want my csv file to look like the following:

```
parentName,parentAge,childName,childAge
Theresa,35,Mary,8
Theresa,35,Jason,10
Theresa,35,Ashley,15
Sheila,19,Tori,2
```

I already have my java code together and can parse the xml but I need help handling the nested nodes.

In my xsl file, I tried doing this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">parentName,parentAge,childName,childAge
  <xsl:for-each select="//results>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(parentResults/parentName,',',parentResults/parentAge,',',childResults/childName,',',childResults/childAge,'&#xA;')"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

But that gave me:

```
parentName,parentAge,childName,childAge
Theresa,35,Mary,8
Sheila,19,Tori,2
```

I also tried this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">parentName,parentAge,childName,childAge
  <xsl:for-each select="//results>
    <xsl:for-each select="//childResults>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(parentResults/parentName,',',parentResults/parentAge,',',childName,',',childAge,'&#xA;')"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

But that gave me:

```
parentName,parentAge,childName,childAge
,,Mary,8
,,Jason,10
,,Ashley,15
,,Tori,2
```

I also tried this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">parentName,parentAge,childName,childAge
  <xsl:for-each select="//results>
    <xsl:for-each select="//parentResults>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(parentName,',',parentAge)"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:for-each select="//childResults>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(',',childName,',',childAge,'&#xA;')"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

But that gave me:

```
parentName,parentAge,childName,childAge
Theresa,35,Mary,8
,,Jason,10
,,Ashley,15
Sheila,19,Tori,2
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't bother with XSL; you'll get more control, more maintainable code, and more robust behavior by using a DOM parser (like JDOM, XOM, or whatever) and a dedicated CSV library for output (opencsv, supercsv, etc).

Comment: Thanks dnault. I was able to figure out my problem with XSL but I'll also look at your suggestion of using a DOM parser. The change to my XSL to get it to work is:

Answer (score 0):

Thanks dnault. I was able to figure out my problem with XSL but I'll also look at your suggestion of using a DOM parser. The change to my XSL to get it to work is:

```
<xsl:template match="/">parentName,parentAge,childName,childAge
  <xsl:for-each select="//results>
    <xsl:for-each select="//childResults>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(../parentResults/parentName,',',../parentResults/parentAge,',',childName,',',childAge,'&#xA;')"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Great, glad you got it working! You may want to check you have the correct behavior for unusual cases like names containing commas or double quotes (which are special characters that require special handling when generating and parsing CSV).

Comment: Got it. For the possible commas, I'm gonna handle it by doing '&quot;' s around them. I'll have to look at handling double quotes if I have any